# How to kill previous cronjob process when new starts?

Tags: cron, wget

Can't believe I haven't found any answers of this question on the site.

Anyway, I have a cronjob task that I want to run every third minute. If it's not completed when next one starts after 3 minutes, I want the current running one to be killed. NOT the new one to wait. I new one must be started, but the old one must be killed. How do I do this?

Here is my current code:

`*/3 * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_function`

**Anyone know the answer?**

Answer (score 1):

Thick and quick way:

Look at the process ID (PID).

Modify the process to put its PID into a temporary file. If your process is called fred, call the file /var/tmp/fredpid or something like that.

This way, every time the process starts up, it checks for the presence of the temporary file already being there. You must code that functionality of course, not forgetting to make sure the process deletes the temporary file at the end of its execution.

Roughly speaking, the steps are as follows:

(1) If /var/tmp/fredpid exists, snarf the PID from the file

(2) kill the older process running under that PID.

(3) Place the current PID in the temporary file.

(4) resume work.

(5) work ends, remove /var/tmp/fredpid